# kubernetes get values from already deployed pod/daemonset

Tags: kubernetes, containers, daemonset

someone before me deployed daemonset, and configmap is it possible for me to somehow get the values he used ? smth like `kubectl edit <name>` but the edit option has some temporary data in it too - the name of pod with random chars etc. - and to get pure values used in that deployments/daemonset what command would I need to use?

Comment: Are the original YAML files checked into source control?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`kubectl get --export` had bugs like [this](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/28551) and [this](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/24855) and `--export` will be deprecated in k8s `v1.18` per [this link](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/CHANGELOG-1.14.md#deprecations).

```
$ kubectl get --export
Flag --export has been deprecated, This flag is deprecated and will be removed in future.
...
```

`kubectl get -o yaml` can be used to get values of a k8s resource's manifest along with metadata and status of the resource. `kubectl get -o yaml` has the following three sections:

- `metadata`
- `spec` with the values of the k8s resource's manifest
- `status` with the resource's status

Answer (score 1):

How about kubectl get --export?

Comment: that's what I wanted great, but I got another question kinda related, I've been deploying filebeats to clusters on GKE in GCP, and some clusters went smoothly and created 7 pods of filebeat and right now one doesn't the values I got from official site curl -L -O https://raw.githubusercontent.com/elastic/beats/master/deploy/kubernetes/filebeat-kubernetes.yaml

Comment: would you happen to know which part of that values file created 7 pods ? configmanp/daemonset / clusterrolbinding / serviceaccount

Comment: Are all those pods replicas of the filebeats DaemonSet?

Comment: and how can I check that ? the `kubectl describe ` should have it inside or

Comment: kubectl get pods if they are in the default namespace and see if there 're several pods with the same name

Comment: yea there are on all other clusters, but not on the one I'm having issues right now

Comment: They aren't in the default namespace. Use kubectl get pods --namespace=kube-system

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205879/discussion-between-cptdolphin-and-vitor-souza).